# How do I add second trigger function to deployed azure function without deleting existing?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Ì have a deployed Azure function with one running trigger-function in it. Is it possible to add a second trigger function to it through visual studio or powershell? I cannot publish through visual studio because that deletes the trigger function that is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create as many new function as you want, just right click on your project and Add -> New Azure Function
Or
Select it from Add Items

Please note when you create project in visual studio, did you select its type as azure function
If not still you may copy all code of your function class which is already there and make it new simple class and paste.
then you can change its signature to new one and new logic, like following

```
public static class YourNewFunctionClassName
{
[FunctionName("your new function name")]
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
{
// your code here
}
```

Don't worry about delete function through visual studio, its normal it first delete all files and then publish new one. In your next publish when you have more than one functions then it will show all functions which you published.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy it with visual studio, there is a option called `Delete Existing Files`, the default value is true, so uncheck it then deploy and it won't delete your files.

[image]

Comment: This is what I thought too but it still removes previous deployed function.

Comment: You shouldn't be deploying like this.  Use Azure Pipelines or a similar tool.